# Saving more than one field to database using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, server, eloquent

I have a weird problem: I use this code to save data to one field in a database table

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

    if (property_exists((object)$arr[$i], "id")) {
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i]->id)->first();
    } else {
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i][0]->id)->first();
    }

    $port->company_a_json = json_encode($arr[$i]);
    $port->save();
}
```

The thing is when I want to save data to another field in this table it doesn't save anything to both of the fields. I use this code to do that:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

    if (property_exists((object)$arr[$i], "id")) {
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i]->id)->first();
    } else {
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i][0]->id)->first();
    }

    $port->company_a_json = json_encode($arr[$i]);

    if (property_exists((object)$arr[$i], "days")) {
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i]->id)->first();
        $daysToSave = json_encode($arr[$i]->days);
    } else {
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i][0]->id)->first();
        $daysToSave = json_encode($arr[$i][count($arr[$i]) - 1]->days);
    }

    $port->company_a_days = $daysToSave;
    $port->save();
    $ms->addMessageTranslated("success", "port after save days " . json_encode($port) . "", $post);
}
```

the $ms thing at the end is intended to output the $port variable so I can check if the values are saved correctly.
this is the $ms output:

```
port after save days {"id":3,"name":"\tXIAMEN","price_mk":0,"company_a_20":0,"company_a_40":0,"company_a_days":"\"444\"","company_a_json":"[{\"portName\":\"XIAMEN\",\"days\":\"4\",\"id\":\"3\",\"datefrom\":\"02\\\/02\\\/2017\",\"dateTo\":\"02\\\/28\\\/2017\",\"price_x\":4,\"prices_y\":4},{\"portName\":\"XIAMEN\",\"days\":\"12\",\"id\":\"3\",\"datefrom\":\"\",\"dateTo\":\"\",\"price_x\":0,\"prices_y\":0},{\"portName\":\"XIAMEN\",\"days\":\"333\",\"id\":\"3\",\"datefrom\":\"02\\\/08\\\/2017\",\"dateTo\":\"02\\\/23\\\/2017\",\"price_x\":12,\"prices_y\":12},{\"portName\":\"XIAMEN\",\"days\":\"444\",\"id\":\"3\",\"datefrom\":\"02\\\/09\\\/2017\"...,
```

notice the column "company_a_days" updated to 444, which is the wanted value, but inside the physical table the value of "company_a_days" is not updated.

The problem is it does output a correct $port, but in the actual table the changes are not saved.

Comment: Can you post the port table schema and model?

Comment: To get a fresh instance of port from the table, you can use `$port->fresh()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from ukalpa I have finally solved it.

- I used json_encode on the to save to 'company_a_json' and have **not** used json_encode to save to 'company_a_days'.
- In addition, I save `$port` to the row twice, even though it's the same row in both saves, and I even pull this row to `$port` twice, once before each editing of values and save().
- And instead of getting value out of `$arr[$i][0]->days` I use `$arr[$i][count($arr[$i]) - 1]->days`. Don't think it had to do with why it didn't update anything in the first place because the 'company_a_days' column had no value at all in the table, and not the one inside `$arr[$i][0]->days`.

Also added a check if `->days > 0` but that's just something concerning my own assignment.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    if(property_exists((object)$arr[$i], "id")){
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i]->id)->first();
    }else{
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i][0]->id)->first();
    }
    $port->company_a_json = json_encode($arr[$i]);
    $port->save();
    if(property_exists((object)$arr[$i], "days")){
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i]->id)->first();
        if($arr[$i]->days > 0){
            $port->company_a_days = $arr[$i]->days;
            $port->save();
        }
    }else{
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i][0]->id)->first();
        if($arr[$i][count($arr[$i]) - 1]->days > 0){
            $port->company_a_days = $arr[$i][count($arr[$i]) - 1]->days;
            $port->save();
        }
    }
}
```

`$arr` is an array of json inputs, so `$arr[$i]` is a single json input.
Here's a sample input from `$arr[$i]` to make the whole solution more clear:

`"[{\"portName\":\"HONG KONG\",\"days\":\"33\",\"id\":\"2\",\"datefrom\":\"02\/01\/2017\",\"dateTo\":\"02\/21\/2017\",\"price_x\":20,\"prices_y\":40}]"`

and here is the updated values in the mentioned columns now:

- company_a_json: `{\"portName\":\"HONG KONG\",\"days\":\"33\",\"id\":\"2\",\"datefrom\":\"02\/01\/2017\",\"dateTo\":\"02\/21\/2017\",\"price_x\":20,\"prices_y\":40}`.
- company_a_days: `33`.

this is an example in which the json is a single object and is taken care of inside these ifs:

- `if (property_exists((object)$arr[$i], "id"))`
- `if(property_exists((object)$arr[$i], "days"))`

  As oppose to the `else` parts where it takes care of json arrays that could be an input too. Guess its not the neatest code ever but i'm on a deadline and at least it works now :)

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

After reviewed your code, I assume ['company_a_days'] should have been changed, but ['company_a_json'] has not been changed because you re-got the object $port again in the section of getting "days", you should remove getting $port again in the second part.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

    if (property_exists((object)$arr[$i], "id")) {
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i]->id)->first();
    } else {
        $port = Port::where('id', $arr[$i][0]->id)->first();
    }

    $port->company_a_json = json_encode($arr[$i]);

    if (property_exists((object)$arr[$i], "days")) {
        $daysToSave = json_encode($arr[$i]->days);
    } else {
        $daysToSave = json_encode($arr[$i][count($arr[$i]) - 1]->days);
    }

    $port->company_a_days = $daysToSave;
    $port->save();
    $ms->addMessageTranslated("success", "port after save days " . json_encode($port) . "", $post);
}
```

Comment: Nope, still exactly the same unwanted result. And btw  ['company_a_days'] have not changed in the table.

Comment: Actually when I put `$port->save()` after `$port->company_a_json = json_encode($arr[$i]);` then it saves to 'company_a_json' so I have some progress here but still not saving to 'company_a_days'

Comment: Some tries:1. Try to use $port['company_a_days'] to save value, 2. Do not json_encode the value and try to save the value first, it may be caused by corrupted json data.

Comment: Well I'll try the first 1 u proposed since as I already told it saves to 'company_a_json' so there's no corrupted json data I guess.